# How to use .schema to display tables that Django creates?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, schema

I was following the Django tutorial [Writing your first Django app, part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/),

> it mentions using .schema in the command-line client, sqlite3.exe in my case, to display the tables Django created on running the command
>   `python manage.py migrate`.

I am new to SQLite, and the SQLite tutorial [SQLite Describe Table](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-describe-table/) doesn't seem to help me much.

I have tried opening the database via sqlite3 binary(also tried run as administrator) but I cannot open the database.
Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run the sqlite3 binary and open your database file. Let's assume your database file is called db.sqlite3 and lives under C:\Users\*your_user_name*\my_project.

- double-click on sqlite3.exe to go straight to the sqlite3 shell
- user the .open command to open your database: `.open C:\Users\<your_user_name>\my_project\db.sqlite3`

This should get you in the sqlite3 shell with your database ready to be explored. Once there, you'll be able to use .schema or any other sqlite commands (check .help for inspiration).